# Proving inequalities using mathematical induction

Tags: analysis

I have this question: 
$n\cdot n>2(n+1)$ where $n$ is greater than or equal to three

I have solved for the $n=1$ and $n=k$. But it's how I do $n= k+1.$

Pls I really need help. Need to submit this in the morning

Comment: You should show more of what you tried in your question! We are all glad to help, we love math but are not here to just do your homework. Show us that you made some effort!

Answer (score 0):

For $n=3$, clearly $3^2=9> 8 = 2(3+1)$. Assume now that $n^2>2(n+1)$ for some integer $n\geqslant 3$. Then
$$
(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2n + 1 > 2(n+1) + 2n+1 > 2(n+2),
$$
so by induction we conclude that $n^2>2(n+1)$ for all integers greater than or equal to $3$.